# Google maps API vs Library

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What is the difference between the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details) and the [Google Places Javascript Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)?

The documentation for the Library doesn't talk about API keys, and as I was developing locally everything seemed to work just fine without one. But shortly after deploying the web app, it started throwing the following errors:

```
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2Fopensaq.dev%2F&5e1&callback=_xdc_._obke7w&token=16494 403 (Forbidden)

GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/PlaceService.FindPlaces?1m6&1m2&1d4…SAQ&6sliquor_store&8e1&18m2&1b1&10u43536&callback=_xdc_._266p5k&token=1150 403 (Forbidden)

GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent?1shttp%3A%2F%2Fopensaq.dev%2F&4e1&5e0&6u1&7s2v1zkm&callback=_xdc_._dacmzn&token=54694 403 (Forbidden)
```

Did exceed a quota or something? What is each option intended for?

Comment: Dont care about the network-traffic. When there is an error the API will tell you, usually via the status-property of the service-response.

Answer (score 2):

The library is a javascript API to make working with the API from JavaScript easier, as it has a set of objects that replace the direct API calls.  It will call the API, so you have to conform to the requirements of the API limits.  The library may also download related JS libraries that are needed to perform the operation too.

These rejections in theory could be the JS library relationships failing to download, but appear to be API rejections.  This could be due to a limit, or a firewall restriction (if you have one or a proxy in place).  Depending on the requirements of the API, some require a signature to be generated, and if that is missing, it will be forbidden too.  Look in the documentation for what it returns 403; the API documentation usually spells it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I overlooked this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

It appears that I'm missing an API key.